# la4j - Adding row or column in matrix

Tags: java, matrix, la4j

I'm currently using [la4j](http://la4j.org/) to perform operations with matrices. Is there an any efficient way to add row or column to existing matrix in between other rows and columns? 
I tried with:

```
matrix.setRow(0, Vector.fromArray(myDoubleArray));
matrix.setColumn(0, Vector.fromArray(myDoubleArray));
```

However, `setRow and setColumn` overwrites existing row/column in matrix.

For example, goal is to transform this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

to this:

```
6 5 1
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

when I add new first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, there [`insertRow`](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/la4j/Matrix.java#L1038) and [`insertColumn`](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/la4j/Matrix.java#L1063) methods that do the trick.